# How is recwatch supposed to work?

Tags: go

I'm trying to get [recwatch](https://godoc.org/github.com/xyproto/recwatch#pkg-index) to work. I'm confused by its interface, though. Yes, I can make a watcher and add folders to it, but there does not seem to be a way to start an event loop that will allow me to receive notifications.

In the [original code](https://github.com/nathany/looper/blob/bc28a212ab3643c208f17fc7bfb628671cb018c3/watch.go#L48), there was a `Run` receiver for just this purpose.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The watcher starts emitting events as soon as it is created. All that's required is to read them from `RecursiveWatcher.Watcher.Events`.  Example:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/xyproto/recwatch"
)

func main() {
    w, err := recwatch.NewRecursiveWatcher("sample_dir")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    for {
        select {
        case event := <-w.Events:
            fmt.Printf("Event: %s\n", event)
        case event := <-w.Errors:
            fmt.Printf("Error: %s\n", event)
        }
    }
}
```